# Convert rank to percentage

Tags: statistics

If I have a series of counties ranked 1-95, 1 being the highest and 95 being the lowest and I want to convert that to percentage with 0 being the lowest and 100 being the highest. Would (1-(rank/95))*100 do that for me?

Comment: I'd go for 100*(rank-1)/94

Comment: Percentage of what? You should first ask yourself such a question and then determine the answer based on that.